# Adding days to date, outputting incorrect dates?

Tags: php, date

I'm having an issue getting my code to add a day depending on the result of a drop down, the drop down values are 1-6 and the held in a variable `$changeDate` and depending on each adds the corresponding amount of days onto my current date. However, for some reason the output day isn't working correctly.

```
$currentDate = "01/02/2003";

if($changeDate == "1"){
    $newDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($currentDate.' + 1 days'));
}
elseif($changeDate == "2"){
    $newDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($currentDate.' + 2 days'));
}
elseif($changeDate == "3"){
    $newDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($currentDate.' + 3 days'));
}
elseif($changeDate == "4"){
    $newDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($currentDate.' + 4 days'));
}
elseif($changeDate == "5"){
    $newDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($currentDate.' + 5 days'));
}
elseif($changeDate == "6"){
    $newDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($currentDate.' + 6 days'));
}

echo $newDate;
```

Results of `$changeDate == 1`: 03/01/2003

Results should be: 02/02/2003

Results of `$changeDate == 2`: 04/01/2003

Results should be: 03/02/2003

Results of `$changeDate == 3`: 05/01/2003

Results should be: 04/02/2003

Results of `$changeDate == 4`: 06/01/2003

Results should be: 05/02/2003

Results of `$changeDate == 5`: 07/01/2003

Results should be: 06/02/2003

Results of `$changeDate == 6`: 08/01/2003

Results should be: 07/02/2003

Comment: Dates in nn/nn/nnnn format are considered MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: Dates with a `/` in are assumed to be the American style dates i.e. Month/Day/Year

Comment: If you convert `/` to `-` they will work as expected

Comment: So the best option would be to reformat `$currentDate` and after reformat `$newdate`

Comment: Should just need to reformat `$currentdate`

Comment: change from $currentDate = "01/02/2003";  to $currentDate = "2003-02-01";

Comment: @RiggsFolly Perfect issue resolved! Thank you!